Asymptotic behavior of the "Cauchy square" series
$\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}\renewcommand{\le}{\leqslant}$
$\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}$
Let us take $\alpha > 0$, $x_1 := \alpha$ and for any $n \ge \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align*}
\boxed{x_n := \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} x_{n-s} x_s,}
\end{align*}
There exist $\xi,c \in \mathbb{R}_+$, such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation}
x_n \le c  (\xi \alpha)^n n^{-\frac 32}. \qquad\qquad (EQ1)
\end{equation}
Two series are equivalent if their quotient goes to $1$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$. Numerical evidence suggests that
\begin{align*}
\boxed{x_n \underset{\substack{n \rightarrow +\infty}}{\sim} \; c \; \frac{(\xi \alpha)^n}{n^{\frac 32}}}
\end{align*}
with $\xi = 4$ and $c = \frac{1}{\xi \sqrt{\pi}}$. Would anyone know how to prove this numerical evidence please ? It's a "Cauchy square" in some sense so I guess the series has already been studied ? The proof of (EQ1) below gives an idea of the mechanisms. With the $S_n$ in the proof, numerical evidence suggests that $S_n \underset{\substack{n \rightarrow +\infty}}{\sim} 5.2247 / n^{\frac 32}$.

Remark : Take $\beta$. If we can prove the numerical conjecture, then we can deduce that if $y_1 = \alpha$ and $y_n = \beta \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} y_{n-s} y_s$, then $y_n \underset{\substack{n \rightarrow +\infty}}{\sim} \; c  (\xi \alpha \beta)^n n^{-\frac 32}$ with $c = \frac{1}{\beta \xi \sqrt{\pi}}$, just by renormalization $y_n = x_n/\beta$. In other words the case $\beta = 1$ implies the general case. We could have normalized to make $\alpha = 1$, but we cannot normalize such that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal to 1.

Proof of (EQ1)
Let us prove (EQ1) inductively. Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 2$, such that for any $s \in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$, $x_s \le c (\xi\alpha )^s s^{-\frac 32}$. Then
\begin{align}\label{eq:bound_xn_interm} 
x_n \le c^2 \pa{\xi\alpha}^n \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\pa{s(n-s)}^{\frac 32}} = c^2 \pa{\xi\alpha}^n S_n,
\end{align}
where for any $x \in ]0,n[$ we define $g(x) := \pa{x(n-x)}^{-\frac 32}$ and want to estimate $S_n := \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} g(s)$ for any $n \ge 2$. By Carlo and Henri, we have $n^{3/2} S_n \rightarrow 2 \zeta(3/2) \simeq 5.2247$, we can also show easily that $S_n \le \frac{\xi}{n^{\frac 32}}$ where $\xi = 10$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
x_n \le ( \xi c) c  (\xi \alpha)^n n^{-\frac 32}.
\end{align*}
We take $c = 1/\xi$ and the recursive equation is proved. Now for $n=1$ the right hand side of (EQ1) is $\alpha$ so the initial step is also valid.

Where does the "4" (of the numerical insight) could come from ? One possible starting point is presented here.
The function $g$ is decreasing on $]0,n/2]$, increasing on $[n/2,n[$, and for any $x \in ]0,n/2]$, $g(n-x) = g(x)$. By a series/integral comparision, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{n-1} g \le S_n - g\pa{\frac n2}, \qquad S_n + g\pa{\frac n2} \le g(1) + g(n-1) + \int_1^{n-1} g
\end{align*}
when $n \in 2 \mathbb{N}$ and
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{n-1} g \le S_n - g\pa{\frac{n-1}{2}}, \qquad  S_n + g\pa{\frac n2} \le g(1) + g(n-1) + \int_1^{n-1} g
\end{align*}
when $n \in 2 \mathbb{N} +1$, hence for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge 2$,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{n-1} g \le S_n \le \frac{2}{(n-1)^{\frac 32}}  + \int_1^{n-1} g.
\end{align*}
Defining $G(x) := \frac{n-2x}{\sqrt{x(n-x)}}$ we have $G'(x) = -\frac{n^2}{2} g(x)$ so
\begin{align*}
    \int_1^{n-1} g = \frac{2}{n^2} \pa{G(1) - G(n-1)} = \frac{4 (n-2)}{n^2\sqrt{n-1}} \underset{\substack{n \rightarrow +\infty}}{\sim} \; \frac{4}{n^{\frac 32}}.
\end{align*}
For any $n \ge 2$, $\frac{n-2}{\sqrt{n-1}} \le \sqrt{n}$ so $\int_1^{n-1}g \le 4 n^{-\frac 32}$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{n^{\frac 32}} \pa{1 - \frac{2}{n} } \le S_n \le \frac{6}{n^{\frac 32}} \pa{1 + \frac{2}{n} }.
\end{align*}

$\gamma=1/\sqrt{\pi}$.

Indeed, verified to relative precision $10^{-3} $, thanks !

You can reduce the evaluation of $S_n$ to a quadrature by means of the Abel-Plana formula,
$$S_n=\sum _{s=1}^{n-1} g(s)=\int_1^{n-1}g(s)\,ds+\tfrac{1}{2}g(1)+\tfrac{1}{2}g(n-1)$$
$$\qquad\qquad -\,2\operatorname{Im}\int_0^\infty \frac{g(1+i y)-g(n-1+i y)}{e^{2 \pi  y}-1}\,dy$$
$$\qquad=\frac{5n^2-12n+8}{(n-1)^{3/2} n^2}-4\operatorname{Im}\int_0^\infty \frac{g(1+i y)}{e^{2 \pi  y}-1}\,dy,$$
where $g(s)=[s(n-s)]^{-3/2}=g(n-s)$.
The integral can be expanded in a power series in $n$, to leading order I find
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{3/2}S_n=5-4\operatorname{Im}\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+iy)^{-3/2}}{e^{2\pi y}-1}\,dy=5.224751\cdots$$
I don't think this integral has a closed-form expression.

Thanks to Carlo, using Abel--Plana once again one finds the simple formula
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2}S_n=2\zeta(3/2)$$

wow, so this integral does have a closed form expression, cool!

@CarloBeenakker: well, whether $\zeta(3/2)$ is a "closed form expression" is debatable, no?
